# Using Jest with Async Server Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a React Server Component, which returns a Promise. The standard `render` method in Jest doesn't like that.

I checked the similar questions, but all are > 4 years old and deal with `componentDidMount` etc.

```
/// Home.tsx
async function Home(props: Props) : Promise<JSX.Element> {
 // call async functions to setup component
}

/// home.test.ts
describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders a heading', () => {
     render(<Home />);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
'Home' can not be used as a JSX element
```

Any suggestions on how to work around this? An obvious solution is to make the component not return a Promise, but than I'm writing code to satisfy the test framework which is not ideal.

Comment: What is jests standard `render` method?

Comment: Objects are not valid as react children. Are you using Next? Set up your component with something like `getServerSideProps` then pass that to your component.

Comment: `render` is not part of Jest. You must be using some other library for that. Are you using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render)?

Comment: `render` is most likely from react-testing-library, but this is not very important to the question at hand. There is no documentation on how to test React Server Components that are available in Next.JS 13.4. If anyone has achieved this, an answer would be awesome!

Comment: WIP docs: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1209#issuecomment-1569813305

Comment: @Paul van Brenk Can you check your React version please? Easiest way is `import { version } from "react"`. If you're using a meta framework like Next, don't use `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Happened upon this while looking through the bounties. I am not sure what all you have tried but I may be able to help. Obviously you know that Jest's can't return a Promise. However there may be a workaround by using act from test-utils. Try something like this

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders a heading', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      render(await Home());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this actually work? We expect answers to be verified, not speculative.

Comment: It does work but without the full code I can't confirm that it will work in this specific case. However I have used it before to get around a similar issue

Comment: This isn't a complete integration testing solution as it doesn't support async child components or other React Server Component features like Server Actions and Next app router.